# GROUP BY custom field

Tags: soql, api, custom-field, php, group-by

I'm doing this query:

```
 SELECT
      ID, Name, Email_Domain__c
    FROM
      Contact
        GROUP BY Email_Domain__c
```

And I'm getting this error

> MALFORMED_QUERY: GROUP BY Email_Domain__c ^ ERROR at Row:5:Column:12
>   field 'Email_Domain__c' can not be grouped in a query call

Is there a way form to `GROUP BY` a custom field?

Pretty much what I want to do is in one call, get the domains for all the emails from the Contact object.

**UPDATE**

When I check this field in workbench, it has these 2 properties

```
calculatedFormula: RIGHT(Email,((LEN(Email)-(FIND("@",Email)))))

groupable: false
```

Comment: I think you answered your own question.

Comment: But, is there a way to make it groupable?

Comment: Pretty much what I want to do is in one call, get the domains for all the emails from the Contact object.

Comment: I see that formulas of types with "dense" set of expected values are groupable (like boolean or date) while "sparse" types are not groupable (e.g. string, dateTime, double)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's possible to group by custom fields in general, but not all field types are groupable.

The docs aren't particularly helpful from what I can see, and just tell you a field is groupable if it's describe field result has a groupable value of true.

IFIRC, you can group by pretty much anything, except DateTime, Long Text Areas, and Formulas, but unfortunately I can't seem to find any explicit documentation of this.

If you want to group by a formula field you can get by with by having creating a copy of the field and having workflow populate it, e.g. whenever your email domain field changes, do a field update that puts the value into the email domain (text) field.  You can then use that to group.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
SELECT Email_Domain__c
    FROM
      Contact
        GROUP BY Email_Domain__c
```

I agreed to Mr Ralph what is said .