# SOQL Query duplicate Clean Phone number

Tags: soql

I want to fetch duplicate records based on phone number. I have written soql query on devconsole like

```
List<Account>Ac=[Select Id, CSS_CustomerID__c, Customer_ID__c, 
    Customer_ID_ReadOnly__c,AFrontier_Prospect_Code__c,CSS_Prospect_Code__c,    
    IOG_Customer_ID__c, RecordType.Name, CleanPhone__c, CleanPhoneText__c, 
    CSS_ListingTel__c, Phone, CreatedDate  
 from Account group by CleanPhone__c having count(CleanPhone__c) > 1];
```

but its not working. Anyone have idea?

Comment: what is not working? please include more details, take some time to read [ask]. thanks

Answer (score 0):

For finding a duplicate record, you need to `group` by the particular field you need to find duplicate on(`CleanPhone__c`) , in your case. Then use aggregate function `count` any other field

Use this query, in your case:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), CleanPhone__c
FROM Account 
GROUP BY CleanPhone__c
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC
```

Comment: Hi Hemant, I got error on workbench like field 'CleanPhone__c' can not be grouped in a query call

Comment: Some fields are not groupable, refer these links: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/what-makes-a-field-not-groupable https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/35018/group-by-custom-field